# Normalizr – is it possible to conditionally remove an entity?

Tags: javascript, normalizr

So I'm using normalizr to massage some data how I see fit. However, some of the entities that are passed through normalizr are not needed by my application. Is there a way to throw out an entity using process strategy or something similar? Thanks!

```
const testSchema = new schema.Entity('things', {}, {
  idAttribute: thing => `${thing.id}`,
  processStrategy: (value, parent, key) => {

  if(!obj.mapping[value.fields.id]){
    // If we get in here, this entity is not needed as 
    // there is no mapping available.
    // How can i throw this entity out?
  }

  return {
    ...value.fields,
    prop: obj.mapping[value.fields.id].mapped_thing,
    prop2: obj.mapping[value.fields.id].mapped_thing2,
    prop3: obj.mapping[value.fields.id].mapped_thing3
  }  
 }
});
```

Is something like this possible? Or is there a better method to remove entities?